# Is sending passwords over cURL secure?

Tags: linux, curl

I am trying to extract data from a webpage that requires a login.
I have tried using the --user flag but it hasn't worked.

I am trying this guide: https://journalxtra.com/linux/howto-pass-data-variables-to-curl-to-autofill-web-forms/

It uses the -d flag to fill in the fields on a webpage.

It seems to work better, but I wanted to know if I should worry about security when sending usernames and passwords in this way.

If so, is there another way to fill username and password fields on webpages?

Apologies if this is a silly question or has been asked already.

Edit: The site uses HTTPS and all other users on the network and system are trusted

Thank you,
John

Comment: It's exactly as secure as doing the same thing in the browser — which might range from "fairly secure" to "not at all" depending on information not provided in the question. Either way, it's not much of a programming question.

Comment: What information could I include to make the question more clear?

Comment: Is the URL HTTP or HTTPS?  Do you trust the other users on the machine where you are running your program?

Comment: Do you have other user on the machine that `curl` is running on? Other users can see the `-d ` command line arguments, potentially revealing the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said in the comments already, it's about as secure as doing the same in the browser.

> It seems to work better, but I wanted to know if I should worry about security when sending usernames and passwords in this way.

I've done this plenty of times, writing scripts to automate some action that has no good api (or perhaps access to the api is expensive?), the security implications is usually only "my password is stored in plaintext in some source code" - other than that, it's the same security issues that you have in a browser.